# PHP file upload - check file size of files larger than .ini max?

Tags: php

My hosts server has an .ini upload_max_filesize of 4mb. I have written some PHP which checks the file size of the upload and throws an error if that size is exceeded. Problem is if the file they are trying to upload is larger than the .ini setting of 4mb my code doesnt get executed as the $_FILES variable shows file size of 0 and error code 1. Is there a way i can check the size of an upload that is bigger than what is set in .ini??

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check whether a file is bigger than allowed size before the user has tried to upload it.

PHP is a server-side programming language, it takes the flow control **after** the webserver handled the request completely.

And your code gets the control **after** some internal php routines have been performed (such as handling file uploads, slashing request strings, filling superglobals, etc)

So the most correct scenario for you to follow is to check if error appeared during file upload and behave accordingly.

Comment: so all i can do is:

check if - $_FILES['file']['error'] == 1

Comment: @Pjn2020: not `if ($_FILES['file']['error']) == 1`, but `if ($_FILES['file']['error'])`. If it is not `0` - then something bad happened.